# Use Unified Remote on Fedora over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, remote-control

Unified remote server works perfectly with one error `Bluedtooth: Could not connect to SDP`.

I tried running sdptool browse local and it claims `Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

This is a two part problem. First SDP is disabled by default due to it's requirement of deprecated Bluez server features. You'll need to start the bluez server in compatibility mode by changing ExecStart to

/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service

```
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
```

Unified remote normally runs as the current user and by default SDP is restricted to root only. To solve thin run `sudo chgrp mygroup /var/run/sdp` to give yourself permission.

If all goes well you should be able to run `sdptool browse local` without root and receive a list of devices.

Afterwards you'll need to restart the unified remote server, there is a button for it in the configuration page, which might be at http://localhost:9510

source #1: http://ryanglscott.github.io/2014/07/17/bluetooth-sdp-on-fedora/

source #2: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201672